# How to do Availability Test for SQL Database Resource in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, availability

Am working on Log Analytics,Application Insights and alerts in Azure. Here,I can easily doing availability test for my Web Applications to know my application availability. Same as this, am trying to do availability test for SQL Database and Storage Accounts. With the help of metrics am able see availability of storage account, but in the case of SQL database am not able to do availability test. Is there any way to do Availability Test for SQL Database resource, If it is there Please suggest me to "How to do it"

Answer (score 1):

Availability Tests in Application Insights support Multi-step tests. With them it is possible to test REST APIs (with authentication flow or hardcoded tokens). SQL Azure supports REST API for CRUD (management) operations. If this is enough for availability for your case - it should work.

Another approach - stand up something simple (Azure Function?) which will run queries your business logic needs to check for availability. Then point Availability Tests in Application Insights to this Azure Function.

Availability Tests in Application Insights don't support DB protocols.